# Infer params and return types based on generic interface

Tags: typescript

I am building a function which accepts an interface and I want this to infer the return types from the 'key' in my options object passed as a function param

My desired results would be something like this reduced code example:

```
const stringKeyValue = createKeyValueMapped<{a: string, b: number}>({
 key: "a", // key: "a"
 value: "hi",  // value: string
 transform: (value) => value + ' more text', // (value: string) => string
}); 

stringKeyValue.key;  // key: 'a'
stringKeyValue.value; // value: string
```

But with my current code the `key` type is `'a' | 'b'` and the value type is `'string' | 'number'`.

My current broken solution is:

```
export type KeyValue<
  Inputs,
  Key extends keyof Inputs,
  Value = Inputs[Key]
> = {
  key: Key;
  value: Value;
  transform: (value: Value) => Value;
};

type KeyValuesMapped<Inputs> = {
  [Key in keyof Inputs]: KeyValue<Inputs, Key>;
}[keyof Inputs];

const createKeyValueMapped = <Inputs,>({ key, value }: KeyValuesMapped<Inputs>) =>
  ({
    key,
    value,
  });
```

I have tried to create a type for `KeyValue` which includes the options inside a function and type the returns but the completely breaks the mapping.

Fuller example is in this [Link to Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIFcDOYD2BbASRAAd0xNkBvAWAChlk4AuZbKUAcwG46GAjFm0496yHCAgsQ6PH2giAvnToB6FWigQ4YTq04AbFDHQgEO8RQDuOKAGsKAC2gRltCAA9iNsMjABPYhQAaQg-ADU4fXQIAB5eZCJScgAaeIA5ODwUD0gQABMKW1CcGASSMkxU0QiolABeMqTMAG0MrIBdOgA+ZAaaUSK-FjaIEQYAN0jolhrosd8oOBBMGBs8FgAKSdqZqYgASl6e2dG6BRE6BAsfBE1tCABlA0ewdhAORLJe5A3+hkGqhM9lUFCwQuE9jEMNh8J8UsgAERwBFdQ51Hq-eIA+LbaIg-YXWhXZY+TDPB6vThw763LSQJ7vQwUt4fcpgTEDUIsJEI5LINTIax2TAAQmQg25yJxe25DmAvIYAqF9jFuMkrEp73iryWKzWmzVaJ6auQAGpkAByZB4GwoSDuMAWvlKmwqn5qwSajhGjUss4EuhkxkvFlwgB0gy4-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-WofRNc0rRtAT7UdRqHygq8+u9I48o4JDDzAJxMBQYhuMyChuLtAIfJLGxNDMfQ-FcJaCojUJKOQJiACUAHkACEABkAFEFJFMU8ggMlNF84AKEAHAJdwtJNAFwCZAAFoEZLdAoE0cBkFB5AIYTezSmhXt1OhwMvVujND2e97vt+-7AeAYH0fBvM6NhhHEYQZHUZ8DGwd6r1kAAHxg0jCZyly6IKmk3JKyLajK2K8dhfsaqxBMz33O9urdU9zza9Vb0VKi3UZ0i311T9vwW6I-0AkD-zmnCLfVOj4ON2gsoezbAZ2va8AO6bjt8q4UYgC6rsksXpeiO6-Ae8nPp+v7kABoGTq5yGYfh1n2YgNHU+x4pcZ7BWmmF8OzMj0nmNeuOqYYJPaZThnaKFjPM6DnPG8W3mBaZuggA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, the `key` property is not generic. The function does not know or care which value you pass to it. The output type can therefore not change based on the `key`.

---

The "easy" solution would be to add a generic type for `key`.

```
const createKeyValueMapped = <
  Inputs, 
  K extends keyof Inputs
>({ key, value }: KeyValue<Inputs, K>) =>
  ({
    key,
    value,
  });
```

The caller would have to specify the key explicitly when calling the function since [TypeScript does not support partial type inference](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242) yet.

```
const stringKeyValue = createKeyValueMapped<CustomInputs, "a">({
  key: "a",
  value: "hi",
  transform: (value) => value + ' more text',
});
```

---

If we want to avoid explicitly setting the second generic type, we can use currying.

```
const createKeyValueMapped = <Inputs,>() =>
  <K extends keyof Inputs>({key, value}: KeyValue<Inputs, K>) => ({
    key,
    value,
  });

const stringKeyValue = createKeyValueMapped<CustomInputs>()({
  key: "a",
  value: "hi",
  transform: (value) => value + ' more text',
});
```

The outer function takes an explicit generic type while the inner function infers the `key`.

```
stringKeyValue.key; // "a"
stringKeyValue.value; // string
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIFcDOYD2BbASRAAd0xNkBvAWAChlk4AuZbKUAcwG46GAjFm0496yHCAgsQ6PH2giAvnToB6FWigQ4YTq04AbFDHQgEO8RQDuOKAGsKAC2gRltCAA9iNsMjABPYhQAaQg-ADU4fXQIAB5eZCJScgAaeIA5ODwUD0gQABMKW1CcGASSMkxU0QiolABeMqTMAG0MrIBdOgA%20ZAaaUSK-FjaIEQYAN0jolhrosd8oOBBMGBs8FgAKSdqZqYgASl6e2dG6BRFXBAsfBE1tCBDwvYBZOGJAvN7kGMSK5K6Noc6l14jEgsgchB8oViqVfuQAZRBslkNtogoWI8Tj9yilkEEukCeht%20gwGMj4hM9lUGAp9hdaFdlj4hCAOFi9l9blpIBzaq93hA8jEMNh8PDMAD9iT4oMWAAiODymmovYKhzAZXxMCLZarKDrZBbPZE1W1ZAAamQAHJkHgbChIO4wNaqnSGaz2aETgA6QZcZBqZCK%20V0T186I%20tGjQPqT2uIA)

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, didn't Matty want  `stringKeyValue.value; // number` ?

Comment: @RobertRendell - Good point. I see some inconsistency. While he does say `number` in the question, he used `string` in his playground but also number in the end. I guess it's a typo :/

Comment: Sorry, that was a copy/paste error. Thanks for working that out.

Comment: This is a great answer and the types are much simpler than using the mapped type I was using. In your opinion would there be a way to do this without the initial function call, or is that something that would only be possible in future, perhaps with the partial type inferance your mention?

Comment: Yes, the first function call needs to stay until partial type inference is possible. If you ask me, maybe you don't need a function at all depending on the complexity of the real implementation. Maybe a single type would suffice: https://tsplay.dev/werOVN ?